# How to parse my String in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I got some statistics from my Android device. Simply speaking, how can I retrieve each individual field in Excel (I want to do it simply inside Excel without using external language)?

For instance, how can I get the `vel` value `18.5` and store in another cell.

```
Location[gps 40.459137,-87.661198 acc=8 et=+5d16h57m45s127ms alt=194.0 vel=18.5 bear=89.9 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=44]}]
```

**NOTE:** Note that 18.5 can be 7.0 as well. So the length of the value is not always fixed.

Comment: Do you regard VBA as "an external language"? This is almost trivial with VBA. It *is* possible using just spreadsheet formulas, but is on the tedious side.

Comment: Well, just using formulas like the one below.

Comment: I included a VBA solution before I read that. I'll leave it in case you change your mind down the road. In my opinion, using Excel without VBA is needlessly painful. It is a much more powerful tool when you use macros.  @Gary'sStudent's excellent answer can be tweaked so as to be more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution:

```
Function GetVel(s As String) As Double
    Dim fields As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    fields = Split(s)
    For i = LBound(fields) To UBound(fields)
        If fields(i) Like "vel=*" Then
            GetVel = Val(Split(fields(i), "=")(1))
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Once you enter it in a standard code module, you can use it like a worksheet function:

[image]

Comment: oh I see. For each file I have to repeat it, or Excel stores it and it becomes permanent?

Comment: Generally, yes -- but you could store them in a personal macro workbook for repeated use (I tend to use that sparingly). It is also possible to create an add-in, but that is somewhat involved. See this for information on personal macro workbooks: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566

Comment: See this: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/personal.htm See especially the author's "Example 2"

Comment: oh sorry. I forgot your answer by using add-in. Let's see if I can make it to work.

Comment: @TinaJ The second link I gave is better than the first. Ron de Bruin's site is a wonderful resource.

Answer (score 2):

With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("vel=",A1)+LEN("vel="),999),FIND(" ",MID(A1,FIND("vel=",A1)+LEN("vel="),999))-1)
```

[image]

Comment: NOTE: Note that 18.5 can be 7.0 as well. So the length of the value is not always fixed. Does it accommodate that?

Comment: @TinaJ  Is there a **space** character after the ***18.5*** ??